# Is it true that the Poynting theorem $P=E\times H$ is quite valid for DC circuits?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, poynting-vector

Can we assume that Poynting's vector theorem $P=E\times H$ is one of the universal laws of physics that applies to electromagnetic fields in AC and DC circuits.Is there A rigorous analysis of arbitrary cases of DC and AC circuit electromagnetic fields shows that Poynting's law $P=E\times H$ applies to both stationary and time-varying electromagnetic fields.

Comment: Why would we need to *assume* anything about the validity of this law? The derivation of Poynting's theorem should *tell* you what situations it is valid for, no?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [Poynting's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem)
$$-\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=
 \vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{S}+\vec{J}\cdot\vec{E}$$
or, equivalently, in integral form
$$-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_V u\ dV=
  \oint_{\partial V}\vec{S}\cdot d\vec{A}
  +\int_V \vec{J}\cdot\vec{E}\ dV$$
is true for all DC and AC cases.

It can be derived from Maxwell's equations, the Lorentz force,
and the definitions of the [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector) $\vec{S}$
and the electromagnetic energy density $u$.
See the section [Poyinting's theorem - Derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem#Derivation).

Answer (score 1):

If something is stationary, it is a special case of being time-varying (with time derivative equals zero). So there is no need to repeat the proof of Poynting's theorem in the narrow sense of stationarity. It is the special case contained in the general case.

However, in the technical analysis of 'DC circuits' the term *'stationary'* is often used synonymous to [*'quasi-stationary'*](https://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/%7Ehees/pf-faq/quasi-stationary-edyn.pdf) in the sense that the circuit does not radiate, i.e. the displacement current $\partial D/\partial t$ in Ampere's law is approximately zero. This understanding is quite reasonable because true DC is comparatively boring in that a system that does not change for the lifetime of the universe does not need any electrodynamics laws to be applied: look at the system today and you know how it looks in 15 billion years. So, of course, every practically relevant system is either dynamic or at most quasi-stationary, which means for a circuit that it does not significantly radiate (or more coarsely speaking: that it is a low-frequency circuit).

Since dropping the displacement current violates charge conservation **and** energy-momentum conservation (remember light and other radiation carries energy and momentum), Poynting's theorem (which is nothing but energy-momentum conservation) is pretty clearly **not** valid for quasi-stationarity. Note that quasi-stationarity is an approximation of Maxwell's theory, and you have not declared what you mean exactly by a 'DC circuit'. If you mean by DC the exact theory for slowly varying fields, Poynting's theorem stays always true, as already noted in the introduction.